# Querying Active Directory in ruby app on Windows box

Tags: ruby, active-directory, ldap

I have a small ruby app in which I'm trying to query some information from Active Directory.  The app will be run by a Windows user who is already logged in.  It looks like the `ruby-net-ldap` gem wants me to connect to an LDAP server using an IP address, port and then pass my username and password.  Is there a way to achieve this (with a different gem, say) so that I don't have to pass this information (I don't have the current user's password for example, so that's not going to work)?

I'm also hosting a Trac website on our intranet (which is written in Python if I remember correctly and that seems to know the current Windows username and domain.  If it can do it, surely my little ruby app can access this information too?

Comment: What information are you trying to gather? I have used `ruby-net-ldap` to authenticate users on AD; I thought (perhaps incorrectly) that you had to be authenticated so that AD knew what data you were even allowed to see.

Comment: Yeah, the weird thing is that I know there are native windows apps that don't have to send their password or LDAP host explicitly before accessing Active Directory information. I assume this is because logging into Windows has already logged you into AD (or a least there's some token that can be used in place of host+user+pwd).

Comment: I am [wrong about IIS being required](http://www.zorched.net/2007/06/04/active-directory-authentication-for-ruby-on-rails/) and about [IE being required](http://sivel.net/2007/05/firefox-ntlm-sso/).

Comment: What will be serving your app? Rails, Ramaze, Sinatra, Rack?

Comment: In my case it will be Rails (v3). I'm thinking I perhaps need a gem that encapsulated Active Directory. There looks to be one but it hasn't been updated for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by using the win32ole gem.  I can now write code like this:

```
require 'win32ole'
ldap_root = WIN32OLE.connect('LDAP://RootDSE')
```